# Triggering jquery not working on large screen

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have this jquery script that triggers when ever I checked a checkbox, it only works fine when ever I change the screen size but not working on large default screen.  Pls help me solution to this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn_click").click(function(a) {
    a.preventDefault();
    alert("I am alert");
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="btn_click">Button</a>
```

The above code works fine when ever I change the screen size to a smaller size

Comment: which screen size its not working?

Comment: It is not working on max-width of 1024px

Comment: As I tested, your code will work great on any screen size

Comment: Do you have any css @media entries that might affect how things work?

Comment: As presented, there's clearly nothing wrong with your code.   Have a read of [mcve].  Start with just a checkbox, jquery and your code.  You'll see it works fine at any resolution.   So you then need to add your other code/components gradually until it stops working, then you'll find where the problem is.

Comment: @freedomn-m Thanks much, i realized that it was because of checkbox that i am checking because it generated dynamically from database. i am going to use another approach to canter that